# Human accessible mathematics : Objects defined by a finite number of steps

Tags: analysis, logic

This is about the uncountable spaces like real numbers : When i was a student, I was proud to talk about them as if they were little toys I could play with.

But ... I once realized that "most" of their elements simply couldn't be mentioned for they couldn't be defined by a finite number of words (or steps.)

The Proof is quite easy : the sub set of the real numbers defined by a finite number of steps is countable. But R is not.

For example :

x = 0.10110111011110111110111111 ... is easy to mention for the decimal sequence that defines it is the result of a simple process. For many other numbers, there is no finite process to define them.

Let us consider Rf the subset of R made of "mentionable" numbers (defined by a finite number of words.) Rf is stable for addition , multiplication , etc ... 
if a and b are mentionable a + b is mentionable.

So Rf has interesting algebraical properties.

It is not a closed subset : a sequence of mentionable numbers might not be mentionable itself :

For example if x is a non-mentionable number, the sequence of its decimal approximations (1 , 1.2 , 1.25 , 1.258 , ...) is made of mentionable numbers but can not be mentioned (if it was, x could be defined as the limit of this sequence and would be mentionable itself.)

This can be done for many other structures. The algebraic stability of the mentionable subset lets me think that some interesting results exist. (mentionable fields like Rf, lead to vector spaces, etc ...) may be there is somewhere a little theory about this all.

I guess I am not the first one to think about this. :o)

This Rf subset of R is surely well known and has a proper name. 
Anybody knows how this is called and where i can find results about this ?
(Sorry if this question is stupid I stopped doing math 20 years ago ...)

THANKS

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/44102/is-the-analysis-as-taught-in-universities-in-fact-the-analysis-of-definable-numb especially Joel David Hamkins' excellent answer.

Comment: You may be interested in "computable analysis". You may also find the theory of "real closed fields" interesting.

Comment: You can see in Wiki [Computable number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_real_number) ; some books also : Errett Bishop, *Foundations of constructive analysis* (1967), Michael Beeson, *Foundations of constructive mathematics* (1985), Klaus Weihrauch, *Computable Analysis An Introduction* (2000), but also the "old" RL Goodstein, *Recursive number theory* (1957 - there is a Dover reprint).

Comment: Thanks for these answers. Of course Joel David Hamkins's answer drew my attention. It showed me that i'ld have to re-open my mathematical logic book if i want to understand the concept rigorously. It is much more subtle than i thought. The fact that he claims that there are some fundamental mistakes in the Wikipedia article seems to me quite significant. One more thing : 20 years ago i was a self taught math student. If there had been a forum like this one, my life would have been changed :o) (i was born too early)

Comment: @minutepapillon - I agree with you; 30 years ago I was a graduate math student, but still I would have liked very much a site like this ! I'm only now understanding (I hope) a lot of things I supposed to have "understood" then ...